# Prove category of constructible sheaves is abelian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a nice enough topological space, perhaps a complex algebraic variety with its analytic topology.  I'm hoping someone could help me prove that the category $\text{Constr}(X)$ of constructible sheaves on $X$ is abelian.

I think one could use that subsheaves and quotients of local systems are local systems.  However, conceptually what is confusing me is that given two constructible sheaves $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$, they might be constructible with respect to completely different Whitney stratifications of X, right?

So given a morphism $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ of constructible sheaves, can you always "refine" the two Whitney stratifications to get one such that the morphism restricts to a morphism of local systems?

Or should I be thinking along another lines?

Comment: There is always a stratification that refines any two given stratifications. Isn’t this almost obvious from the definition?

Comment: @WillSawin I suppose, but is it clear the refinement will be Whitney?  Or is it not true that a constructible sheaf must be locally constant over a *Whitney* stratification?  I've been confused whether you need Whitney in the definition of constructible, because I've seen it both ways.

Comment: I think every stratification of a reasonable space has a refinement that is a Whitney stratification. This would make the two definitions nicely equivalent, and answer this question as well.

Comment: For instance Theorem 2.2 of Verdier's paper seems to be the desired statement https://eudml.org/doc/142424

Comment: @WillSawin Great that makes sense.  Thanks a lot.  If it matters, I would accept it if you wrote this into an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Verdier has proved](https://eudml.org/doc/142424) (for multiple classes of spaces, including in particular complex varieties) that for any finite set of analytic subsets, there exists a Whitney stratification for which all these analytic subsets are unions of strata.

In particular, given two constructible sheaves, and a stratification on which they are lisse, there exists a Whitney stratification that refines both of them.

This suffices to check that kernels and cokernels of maps of constructible sheaves are constructible, as well as direct sums of constructible sheaves.